# Does Apple & Google allow for Horoscope Service to be paid by Paypal rather than IAP?

Tags: android, ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

I've got a Horoscope service to offer by using App from AppStore and PlayStore.
You can ask the questions in the app and The Horoscope result will be delivered using photos.
However, Apple cuts 30% if we use IAP. For an astrologer, such amount is very hight and wondering an alternative way to go around without 30% cut. Please kindly advice me in following questions:

1. Does Apple allow if I want users to pay by Paypal if I deliver
   the results in the app?
2. Does Apple allow if I want users to pay by Paypal if I deliver
   the results to their email?
3. Does Google allow if I want users to pay by Paypal if I deliver the
   results in the app?
4. Does Google allow if I want users to pay by
   Paypal if I deliver the results to their email?

Thank you so much for your help.